# Why won't the if statement run?

Tags: c#

So I am trying to make a chess game (the board is 64 buttons) and I need to check if the button that was first pressed is a certain button but for some reason the code in the if statement will not run.

```
public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (partOfTurn == false)
        {
            //code

            previousButton = (Button)sender;
            partOfTurn = true;
        }

        else if (partOfTurn == true) 
        {
            //code

            click();
            partOfTurn = false;
        }

        void click()
        {
            if (turn == true)
            {
                if (previousButton.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.White_Pown)
                {
                    //unreachable code
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:
People are asking for more info:

partOfTurn identifies if it is the first button press of a turn or the second.

Yes, I did debug it and it looks like it acts like the statement is false when it is true.

White_Pown is a file.

Comment: Did you debug it? Where is the value of `turn` coming from?  Did you compare the value of `BackgroundImage` and `White_Pown`? Have you read what we expect for a [MCVE]?

Comment: You have *4* `if` statements; which "will not run", and how can you tell?

Comment: @ScottHunter It looks like within the click method.

Comment: Well, the code in the `if` will not run, because the condition inside it is false.

Answer (score 1):

Button.BackgroundImage is of type System.Drawing.Image. You said White_Pown is a file. I would not expect these to be comparable.

Comment: After a bit of testing I see that when you import "An existing file" into the Visual Studio project resources editor it does convert the type of the resource to some type of image, depending on the file (bmp, ico, etc.) which would be comparable. However the == operator may only compare its operands as references. Perhaps one image is a copy of the other and not the exact same object. Anyway you should not rely on the image to tell you what piece is in a square.